# How to get more than 1 stock information per call on Google Financials?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-finance-api

I'm using Google Script and Google Financials to get information for a list of stocks I have in a text file. The problem is that the class FinanceApp just seems to be able to get one stock at a time and since I have to do this for more than 250 stocks I reach the maximum call limit.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you are hitting a short term limit, then use an `Utilities.sleep` between calls

Comment: It's more about the long term. The total number of stocks is around 350, so I can make my application call the script twice, but if I test this too much I reach the daily cap and I feel there must be a more efficient way to do this than to keep invoking the service per every stock when the only information I want is the name and price.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are limitations and you are making repeted tests, I suggest using a cache : You can then repeat the test without hitting the limit (assuming you request always the same data for the same date, i.e. using `StockInfoSnapshot`).

You do it by wrapping `FinanceApp.getHistoricalStockInfo()` so that it serves from the cache if possible, or add to it if info is not available.

The cache could conveniently resides in the "script-related storage" : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/script_user_properties

Good luck !